# Android Wear project - with an existing Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, wear-os

I have an existing Android app (for 4.2) written using Eclipse.

I'm exploring the possibility of adding an Android Wear component - there's part of the app which I think could work on a watch.

Reading through the docs at https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html I'm unsure of what I'd need to do in order to integrate Wear into my existing project.

For example, under prerequisites it says Android Studio. Does that mean I'd need to migrate my Eclipse solution into Android Studio? Or can I build the Wear component independently?

Essentially, I'm just hoping to hear from someone who has added a Wear component to their existing Android solution so I can understand the basics of what's involved.

Answer (score 0):

Android Wear is essentially very light application.  The basic processing happens on the handheld device. Only user interaction functionalities such as accept, reject etc. is deplyed to the wear. Here also the processing is carried on by the handheld device.

So yes, you can include Wear to your project if it adds any value.